# How to release the AVAudioPlayer in the below code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, avaudioplayer

I want to release the memory which I allocated for AVAudioPlayer, but when I tried to release it then the sound is not playing.It is potential memory leak, how can I get out of this.

here the below code is used when wrong selection is picked then I am playing the error sound, If I select multiple time wrong selection then It is allocated multiple times then how can I rid out of this.

```
        else
        {
            NSString *soundName=@"Error.mp3";

            NSError *error;
            NSURL *urlString = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%s", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],[soundName UTF8String]]];

            AVAudioPlayer *worngAudioPlay = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlString error:&error];// here I also used to release using autorelease then not played sound

            worngAudioPlay.delegate = self;

            if (worngAudioPlay == nil)
            {
            }
            else
            { 
                [worngAudioPlay play];
            }
            // [worngAudioPlay release]; // Here I released then not played sound
        }
```

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 0):

you can release in avaudio player delegate method named audioDidFinishPlaying. I don't know the name exactly. but you might get an idea what I am talking about

Comment: Hi, But when I stopped then this method is not called.

Comment: @Madan Mohan read the documentation I don't remember the exact method name. You will find that in avaudioplayer class documentation

Answer (score 0):

Make it a retained property of your class, and release it in the dealloc.

In your header file:

```
@property(retain)AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

In your implementation (.m) file:

```
@synthesize player;
```

In your code above:

```
else
{
    NSString *soundName=@"Error.mp3";

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *urlString = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%s", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],[soundName UTF8String]]];

    AVAudioPlayer *worngAudioPlay = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlString error:&error];

    if (worngAudioPlay != nil)
    {
        // this will cause the previous one to be released
        [self setPlayer:worngAudioPlay];
        [worngAudioPlay release];
        worngAudioPlay.delegate = self;
        [worngAudioPlay play];
    }
}
```

In your dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I don't have setPlayer method. I am getting warrning

Comment: If you create the player property in your header file as above, and add "@synthesize player;" to your implementation, the setHeader method is implicit.